# $V=\min \{X,Y\}$ is independent of $W=|X-Y|$

Tags: probability

X,Y are independent random variables.

How can I rigorously prove that $V=\min \{X,Y\}$ is independent of $W=|X-Y|$?

Intuitively, if I know that the minimum of X,Y is X, this information doesn't help me find out how far Y lies from X. And vice versa, if I know that |X-Y| = 5, this doesn't tell me which one is the minimum.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, they are. Sorry I forgot to include this information from the start.

Comment: One more question... do you know for *sure* if $V$ and $W$ are independent or not?

Comment: Yes V and W are independent, but **if one assumes furthermore that** X and Y are exponentially distributed. The OP probably forgot to mention this. As such, the question should probably be closed and I fail to understand why the accepted answer, providing a general (unsound) argument, was accepted (all the more so, two minutes after it was posted). Both other answers actually provide examples where one can conclude.

Answer (score 2):

$V$ and $W$ are not independent in general. Suppose for example
that $X$ and $Y$ share the same distribution with
$P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Then $P(V=2,W=1)=0\neq P(V=2) \times P(W=1)$

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.

Let $X$ be distributed over $\{ -\frac 12, 2 \frac13 \}$ with equal probabilities of both outcomes.
Let Y be distributed over $\{0,1\}$ with equal probabilities as well.

Now, $Y$ is always integer, so if you know that $|X-Y|$ is an integer multiple of $\frac 12$, then necessarily $X = -\frac 12 < Y$ w. p. $1$.

If $|X-Y|$ is a multiple of $\frac 13$, then necessarily $X = 2 \frac 12 > Y$ w. p. $1$.